# Sum all data in array of objects into new array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```js
var data = [
    { costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200 },
    { costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000 },
]
```

and I want to sum each element in the array to produce an array like this:

```js
var result = [ { costOfAirtickets: 4000, costOfHotel: 2200 } ]
```

I have used a map and reduce function but I was able to only sum an individual element like so:

```js
data.map(item => item.costOfAirtickets).reduce((prev, next) => prev + next); // 22
```

At the moment this produces a single value which is not what I want as per initial explanation.

Is there a way to do this in Javascript or probably with lodash.

Comment: Why do you want it to return an array?

Comment: Because I want to loop the array in the angular view.

Comment: But you don't need any loop to handle a single Object.

Comment: An array of objects you mean.

Comment: `costOfHotel` should be `2200` I guess

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee Good spot, fixed now :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `for..in` to iterate object and `reduce` to iterate array

```js
var data = [{costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200},{costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}];

var result = [data.reduce((acc, n) => {
  for (var prop in n) {
    if (acc.hasOwnProperty(prop)) acc[prop] += n[prop];
    else acc[prop] = n[prop];
  }
  return acc;
}, {})]
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This solution is nice, because it allows one to automatically include different properties per trip (`{..., costOfRentalCar: 300}`) .  But it only works if the *only* properties in a trip are costs.

Comment: Instead of `acc[prop]`, use [`acc.hasOwnProperty(prop)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). This prevents that, in some situations, you are checking if there's a `__toString` or something. Also, use `acc[prop] += +n[prop] || 0;` for summing. If I pass a string to it, it will just concatenate. The `+n[prop]` forces it to be converted to integer. The `|| 0` removes other falsy values like NaN. Same thing for `acc[prop] = n[prop]` to be `acc[prop] = +n[prop] || 0`.

Comment: This answer is several years out of date.  People don't use `for...in` + `hasOwnProperty` anymore, use `for(const key of Object.keys(...))` instead. Also this whole thing can be done as a simple one-liner using lodash.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Even simpler, `if (prop in acc) …`

Comment: @Bergi That's not *better*. That's *exactly* what you *shouldn't* do. Try `'toString' in {}`. If it returns `true`, then your code probably can break. `if(proc in acc)` checks if a property exists in the object ***and*** prototype(s). Something you *don't* want here.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I said "simpler", not "better". Apparently you already know all the property names beforehand, so you can rule out `toString` or `hasOwnProperty` from appearing.

Comment: But what if I do `{'toString': 1}`? Or `{'hasOwnProperty': 1}`? Using `({'toString': 1}).hasOwnProperty('toString')` gives `true`. This means that you are intentionally skipping things.

Answer (score 8):

Use Lodash to simplify your life.

```
const _ = require('lodash')
let keys = ['costOfAirtickets', 'costOfHotel']; 
let results = _.zipObject(keys, keys.map(key => _.sum( _.map(data, key))))
...
{ costOfAirtickets: 4000, costOfHotel: 2200 }
```

Explanation:

- `_.sum(_.map(data, key))`: generates sum of each array
- `_.zipObject`: zips the results with the array sum
- using `keys.map()` for sum of each key as `_.map` does not guarantee order.

Documentation:

- sum: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#sum
- zipObject: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#zipObject
- map: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#map

Comment: Your solution doesn't solve the problem asked by the OP which was how to sum an array of objects like such: `var data = [{costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200},{costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}]`

Comment: @DaveKalu: why? `result` contains exactly the asked value. Aren't you the OP? IMO this is the best answer. @Roopak: you can still simplify it a little bit: `_.sumBy(data, key)` or `_(data).sumBy(key)`.

Comment: @DaveKalu: This does solve the exact problem asked. It's also the cleanest answer on this page, and exactly what I was about to write.  Note that `keys` can be defined as `const keys = Object.keys(data);`

Comment: This might be one of the best approach but it needs the keys to be known against which we will perform the sum. In such case (assuming) the other answers can be optimized too (since most of the answers are targeting sum of all the unique properties). Knowing the properties (as input) to perform the sum, will give the advantage that it can be started from the array of properties rather than starting from the actual array (like this solution).

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to map the array, you're really just reducing things inside it.

```
const totalCostOfAirTickets: data.reduce((prev, next) => prev + next.costOfAirTickets, 0)
const totalCostOfHotel: data.reduce((prev, next) => prev + next.costOfHotel, 0)
const totals = [{totalCostOfAirTickets, totalCostOfHotel}]
```

In one go, you could do something like

```
const totals = data.reduce((prev, next) => { 
    prev.costOfAirTickets += next.costOfAirTickets; 
    prev.costOfHotel += next.costOfHotel; 
}, {costOfAirTickets: 0, costOfHotel: 0})
```

Answer (score 6):

To create a resultant / reduced value, you should use `.reduce()` method instead of `.map()`:

```js
let data = [
  {costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200},
  {costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}
];

let result = data.reduce(
  (a, c) => (Object.keys(c).forEach(k => (a[k] = (a[k] || 0) + c[k])), a), {}
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Simplified: `const result = data.reduce((a, c) => (Object.keys(c).forEach(k => (a[k] += c[k])), a))`

Answer (score 5):

Another solution would be to use `Map` (*not Array.prototype.map*) as it has several [notable differences compared to objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared):

```js
var data = [{
  costOfAirtickets: 2500,
  costOfHotel: 1200
}, {
  costOfAirtickets: 1500,
  costOfHotel: 1000
}]

let sums = data.reduce((collection,rcd)=>{
  Object.entries(rcd).forEach(([key,value])=>{
      let sum = collection.get(key) || 0
      collection.set(key, sum + +value)
  })
  return collection
}, new Map())

console.log(...sums.entries())
```

### Explanation

#### Outer loop

The above first iterates over your `data` array using the `reduce` method.  Each object within that I'll be referring to as a record -- distinguished in  the code via the variable, `rcd`.

Each iteration of reduce returns a value which is passed as the first argument to the next iteration of the loop.  In this case, the parameter `collection` holds that argument, which is your set of sums.

#### Inner loop

Within the `reduce` loop, each key/value pair of the record is iterated over using `forEach`.  To get the key/value pair the `Object.entries` method is used.  Using array destructuring these arguments can be directly assigned to the respective variables, `key` and `value`

#### Retrieving/Setting values

Unlike a primitive object, `Map` has its own methods for getting and setting its entries using `get()` and `set()`.  So first retrieve the previous sum using `get()`, if it's not set then default to `0`, which is what the `|| 0` does.  At that point, you can assume the previous sum is at least 0 or greater and add the current key's value onto it.

#### Alternatives to Map

If you find *Map* is a bit heavy-handed, you may also use a similar object such as [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), which has many of the same methods (except the `get()`), or you could also use a primitive object (i.e. `{}`).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `lodash` approach

```
_(data).flatMap(_.entries).groupBy(0).mapValues(v=>_.sumBy(v, 1)).value()
```

It will sum by all the unique keys.

```js
var data = [{costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200},{costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}];

var res = _(data).flatMap(_.entries).groupBy(0).mapValues(v=>_.sumBy(v, 0)).value();

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Wrap your result to a `[...]` or use a `.castArray()` at the end before unwrapping using `.value()` in case you want a array as result.

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array by taking an object for summing.

```js
var data = [{ costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200 }, { costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000 }],
    keys = ['costOfAirtickets', 'costOfHotel'],
    sum = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        keys.forEach(k => r[k] += o[k]);
        return r;
    }, Object.assign(...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: 0 }))));

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Should be the best answer. Easily customizable and dynamic.

Comment: When using typescript to shutdown error: `Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0 or more.ts(2557)
lib.es2015.core.d.ts(313, 12): An argument for 'target' was not provided.` on `Object.assign(...keys` you can do `Object.assign({}, ...keys`

Comment: right, but the whole makes no sense, if you haven't some keys.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `forEach()` loop for that:

```js
var data = [{costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200},{costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}];
var res = [];
var tempObj = {};
data.forEach(({costOfAirtickets, costOfHotel}) => {
  tempObj['costOfAirtickets'] = (tempObj['costOfAirtickets'] || 0) + costOfAirtickets;
  tempObj['costOfHotel'] = (tempObj['costOfHotel'] || 0) + costOfHotel;
 });
res.push(tempObj);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: why brackets for simple properties which works with dot?

Answer (score 1):

Try using reduce only as in the below snippet. Try avoiding multiple iterations. Hope the below snippet helps!

```js
var data = [{costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200},{costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}]

var total = data.reduce(function (result,value,key) {
result['costOfAirtickets'] = result['costOfAirtickets']  + value['costOfAirtickets'];
result['costOfHotel'] = result['costOfHotel']  + value['costOfHotel'];

return result},{costOfAirtickets:0,costOfHotel:0});

console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` the object and calculate the sum and store it in another.

```js
var data = [{costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200},{costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}];
var result = [];
var sum = 0;
var costsum = 0;
data.map(function(item, key){
  var cost = item;
  //nsole.log(cost);
  sum = sum + cost.costOfAirtickets;
  costsum = costsum + cost.costOfHotel;

});

result = [{costOfAirtickets:sum, costOfHotel:costsum}];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest approach I could think off

```
var data = [{costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200},{costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}];
var sum ={};
for(var obj in data){
  for(var ele in data[obj]){
    if(!data[obj].hasOwnProperty(ele)) continue;
      if(sum[ele] === undefined){
        sum[ele] = data[obj][ele];
      }else{
        sum[ele] = sum[ele] + data[obj][ele];
      }
  }

}
var arr = [sum];
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

My simplistic answer would be like;

```js
var data = [{costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200},
            {costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}],
    res  = data.reduce((p,c) => Object.entries(c).reduce((r,[k,v]) => (r[k]+=v, r), p));
console.log(res);
```

A note on usage of `.reduce()`: If the array items and the accumulated value is of same type you may consider not using an initial value as an accumulator and do your reducing with previous (`p`) and current (`c`) elements. The outer reduce in the above snippet is of this type. However the inner reduce takes an array of key (`k`) value (`v`) pair as `[k,v]` to return an object, hence an initial value (`p`) is essential.

The result is the accumulated value as an object. If you need it in an array then just put it in an array like `[res]`.

Answer (score 1):

**Lodash**

Using `lodash` [reduce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#reduce) and [_.mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mergeWith) this is a one liner:

```js
var data = [{costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200}, {costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}]

var result = _.reduce(data, (r,c) => _.mergeWith(r, c, (o = 0, s) => o + s), {})

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**ES6 Only**

If you **do NOT want to mutate** the original array you can utilize ES6 [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) like this:

```js
var data = [{costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200}, {costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}]

// One liner
var result1 = data.reduce((r, c) =>
  !Object.entries(c).forEach(([key, value]) => r[key] = (r[key] || 0) + value) && r, {})

// More readable
var result2 = data.reduce((r, c) => {
  Object.entries(c).forEach(([key, value]) => r[key] = (r[key] || 0) + value)
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result1)
console.log(result2)
```

If we do not care about **mutating** the initial `data` array then we can have a one liner solution:

```js
var data = [{costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200}, {costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}]

data.reduce((r, c) => !Object.entries(c).forEach(([key,value]) => r[key] += value) && r)

console.log(data[0])
```

More readable:

```js
var data = [{costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200}, {costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}]

data.reduce((r, c) => {
  Object.entries(c).forEach(([key, value]) => r[key] += value)
  return r
})

console.log(data[0])
```

The only difference between the mutating and not mutating examples is the **initial value** for the `reduce` (and also the fact that with the mutating we use the 0 index to as an accumulator for the sums). In the mutating ones there is no `initial value` where in the others we start with empty object literal.

if you need the result to be an array specifically then return `[data]` for the mutating examples and `[result]` for the pure examples.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{costOfAirtickets: 2500, costOfHotel: 1200},{costOfAirtickets: 1500, costOfHotel: 1000}];

var result = [data.reduce((acc, n) => {
  for (var prop in n) {
    if (acc[prop]) acc[prop] += n[prop];
    else acc[prop] = n[prop];
  }
  return acc;
}, {})]
console.log(result)
```