# Sum data from two array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two array of objects, and I want to sum the object that have a same key (in this case, id), and if there is no match key, then just create a new one.. I'm sorry if I am not explaining it clearly, I am new to JavaScript/Array/Object thing...

```
var dataOne = [ { id:"1", total: 10, win: 5 }, { id:"2", total: 5, win: 1 }, { id:"3", total: 5, win: 2 } ]
```

and

```
var dataTwo = [ { id:"1", total: 5, win: 2 }, { id:"2", total: 2, win: 3 }, { id:"5", total: 5, win: 4 } ]
```

Expected result:

```
var combinedData = [ { id:"1", total: 15, win: 7 }, { id:"2", total: 7, win: 4 }, { id:"3", total: 5, win: 2 }, { id:"5", total: 5, win: 4 } ]
```

I have tried to use the solution from [Sum all data in array of objects into new array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479107/sum-all-data-in-array-of-objects-into-new-array-of-objects)
but, apparently the type of data is kind of different

So, I tried to use this method from [Javascript - Sum of two object with same properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488048/javascript-sum-of-two-object-with-same-properties)

```
 function sumObjectsByKey(...objs) {
      for (var prop in n) {
        if (acc.hasOwnProperty(prop)) acc[prop] += n[prop];
        else acc[prop] = n[prop];
      }
      return acc;
    }
```

and

```
var combinedData = sumObjectsByKey(dataOne, dataTwo);
```

But apparently, that method won't work for an array of objects.
I get

```
{0: "0[object Object][object Object]", 1: "0[object Object][object Object]", 2: "0[object Object][object Object]"}
```

as a result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Combine both using rest params and `Array.flat()`. Reduce the items into a Map, while combining the current item, with the item that already exists in the Map. Convert the `Map.values()` iterator to an array with `Array.from()`:

```js
const sumObjectsByKey = (sumFn, ...arrs) => Array.from(
  arrs.flat() // combine the arrays
  .reduce((m, o) => // retuce the combined arrays to a Map
    m.set(o.id, // if add the item to the Map
      m.has(o.id) ? sumFn(m.get(o.id), o) : { ...o } // if the item exists in Map, sum the current item with the one in the Map. If not, add a clone of the current item to the Map
    )
  , new Map).values()
)

// utility function to sum to object values (without the id)
const sumItem = ({ id, ...a }, b) => ({
  id,
  ...Object.keys(a)
    .reduce((r, k) => ({ ...r, [k]: a[k] + b[k] }), {})
});

const dataOne = [ { id:"1", total: 10, win: 5 }, { id:"2", total: 5, win: 1 }, { id:"3", total: 5, win: 2 } ]
const dataTwo = [ { id:"1", total: 5, win: 2 }, { id:"2", total: 2, win: 3 }, { id:"5", total: 5, win: 4 } ]

const result = sumObjectsByKey(sumItem, dataOne, dataTwo)
  
console.log(result)
```

Comment: what if i want to add only one column and merge other column ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest `Array.reduce` here. In the body of the reduction function, if the `id` isn't in the result accumulator, add it, then increment all of the values for each property in the object.

```js
var dataOne = [ { id:"1", total: 10, win: 5 }, { id:"2", total: 5, win: 1 }, { id:"3", total: 5, win: 2 } ]
var dataTwo = [ { id:"1", total: 5, win: 2 }, { id:"2", total: 2, win: 3 }, { id:"5", total: 5, win: 4 } ]

var sumObjectsByKey = (...objs) => 
  Object.values(objs.reduce((a, e) => {
    a[e.id] = a[e.id] || {id: e.id};

    for (const k in e) {
      if (k !== "id") {
        a[e.id][k] = a[e.id][k] ? a[e.id][k] + e[k] : e[k];
      }
    }

    return a;
  }, {}))
;

console.log(sumObjectsByKey(...dataOne, ...dataTwo));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I found that the ID went missing.. But then I also found a way to show the ID again, by adding 
      if (k == "id") {
        a[e.id][k] = a[e.id][k] ? a[e.id][k] : e[k];
      }

right after the !== id if end -- edit, just figured out that I cannot use html markdown in the comment